# intern work of char - better/equal to lookup

Tags: c++, c, lookup-tables

i tried the following:

```
int main()
{
    char* a = "sdwgfwegwe wefwef wefwefwefwysadqaw";
    char* b = "acd";
    char* c = "sdwgfwegwe wefwef wefwefwefwysadqaw";
    char* d;

    d = "acd";

    printf("%p\n", a);
    printf("%p\n", b);
    printf("%p\n", c);
    printf("%p\n", d);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

and on the output(console) a and c had the same address as well as b and d.
i thought about implementing a lookup-table for every character.
is there any benefit/situation of doing it?
and what does the compiler makes out of it (the example above, not the lookup-table :) )? check if this string is already used, if not, reserve memory for the given string -> return it to a?
has anybody some book tips or links, that go this deep and explain the internal memory allocations/management, even if it is compiler dependent?
thanks in advance.

Comment: "for every character" - do you mean for every string? "and what does the compiler makes out of it" - huh, what's the question, again?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do and what *exactly* you are asking... Can you elaborate?

Comment: Smart compiler! Saw the same _constant_ string, and created just one copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String literals are specified to be unmodifiable in C.

And from the C99 rationale [document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf):

> "This specification **allows implementations to  share copies of strings with identical text**, to place string
>           literals in read-only memory, and to perform certain optimizations"

Comment: i have to dig into the document, maybe this is exactly what i was looking for... thanks

Answer (score 2):

The C++ answer (§2.14.5):

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation-defined.

It is entirely up to the implementation how it decides to create the string literal objects. One implementation may do it differently to another. Yours appears to treat identical string literals as the same object.

Comment: to the implementation? do you mean implementation of the compiler?

Comment: @immerhart The implementation of the standard. A C++ compiler is an implementation of the C++ standard.